# Passing typescript object which contains array using axios

Tags: java, arrays, typescript, axios

I have a typescript object which has an array of Strings as one of its fields. I want to pass it via axios to my java backend. When I initialize array this way:

```
var numbers = ["1", "2", "3"];
```

it's passed correctly. But when I initialize it this way:

```
var numbers = new Array();      // or just var numbers = [];
```

and then add elements in **for** loop using:

```
numbers.push("some string");
```

I get empty array in my java code...
Another wired thing for me is that, when I initialize array the first way and then add elements in for loop, in java I can retrieve only these static values.

Thats how I make my API request:

```
public create(entity: IMessage, numbers: String[]): Promise<IMessage> {
 return new Promise<IMessage>((resolve, reject) => {
  entity.user = accountStore.state.userIdentity;
  entity.date = new Date();
      
  var dto = new MessageDTO(entity.id, entity.name, entity.content, entity.date, entity.user, numbers);
       
  axios
   .post(`${baseApiUrl}`, dto)
   .then(res => {
    resolve(res.data);         
  })
  .catch(err => {
    reject(err);
  });
 });
}
```

Comment: How does that array *get* to your Java code? Give a [mre], there's no reason you should see different results for the two options you've shown.

Comment: Please [edit] the question, that's all but unreadable as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve this issue.

Data used for filling my array was from external file. I was using FileReader and its function onload. My mistake was to request API before array was filled.

Sorry for bothering you.